# WPF ItemContainerStyle not binding to collection items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a view model object called `ProjectViewModel` that is assigned as my Window's data context. Within the view model, I have an `ObservableCollection<DiaryViewModel>` that I bind to the ItemsSource of a `ListView`. Within the `DiaryViewModel` I have a few properties. The `ListViewItem` items need to be stylized based on what those property values are. When I try to bind to the `DiaryViewModel` associated with the `ListViewItem`, visual studio tells me that the property does not exist. Resharper's Intellisense show's me that the binding is associated with the `ProjectViewModel`. When I type `Path=` the intellisense shows me all of the properties assocaited with the `ProjectViewModel`.

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong? The GridColumns are bound properly to the `DiaryViewModel` properties, just not the `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<Window x:Class="Pen.Views.PenMain"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Pen.ViewModels"
        Title="PEN"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="700"
        Width="1000"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:ProjectViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ProjectViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <ListView Margin="0"
                Name="lvDiaries"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiariesForSelectedProject}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDiaryViewModel}"
                MouseDoubleClick="DiariesDoubleClicked"
                SelectionChanged="lvDiaries_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="DiaryId"
                                Width="0"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Number"
                                Width="50"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="DiaryDate"
                                Width="90"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Inspector"
                                Width="150"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Inspector}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status"
                                Width="130"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                    Value="Supervisor Returned">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                    Value="Office Returned">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>

</Window>
```

Comment: Do you see the problem only in the Visual Studio designer? Or does the problem also occur if you run your application? In the latter case, could you please describe in more detail how the resulting list view differs from what you would have expected?

Comment: Hi fmunkert, the issue is in both designer and runtime. The ListView properly displays each `DiaryViewModel` item in the UI, but each `ListViewItem` within my ItemContainerStyle does not have access to the `DiaryViewModel` object associated with it. Instead, the `ItemContainerStyle` sees the `ProjectViewModel`

Comment: Also, you can see within the GridView, one of the columns can see and access the `DiaryViewModel`'s `Status` property. Why can't the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: I.e. during runtime, you see the text "Office Returned" or "Supervisor Returned" in the the list view, but the text background is not red?

Comment: @fmunkert that is correct. Visual Studio's designer tells me that the `Status` property does not exist, because the XAML sees the parent view model and not the view model associated with the `ListViewItem`

Comment: Actually, your code looks OK to me. If you are getting Resharper's "Cannot resolve property '...' in data context of type '...'" message in the VS designer, then you can ignore that in most cases, because Resharper has not enough information to determine the correct data context (you could try to set the d:DataContext property on the DataTrigger element; I think this works only in VS2013). The only idea I have left is that you use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com ) to find out what type the DataContext property has on a ListViewItem.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting visual studio fixed this problem. The unresolved binding issues at runtime are now properly resolving.